# Remove a specific file from service worker cache?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, browser-cache

I've written code that can return the Response of all files that are no longer in use from a given cache to then delete. I've tried using `cache.delete` already with a request from `cache.matchAll()` here's the request that's returning false.

`Response
{type: "basic"
url: "http://127.0.0.1:5500/bundles/bundle-f6d8ec63.css"
redirected: false
status: 404
ok: false
statusText: "Not Found"
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
}`

You can see here that it does exist in the cache
[image]

It looks like cache.delete is meant for removing whole caches but I only want to remove a few select files. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If I visit the file in the browser I can then delete them normally. The plot thickens...

Answer (score 0):

You can delete items in the cache with `cache.delete(request, options)`.

This method finds the item in the cache matching the request, deletes it, and returns a Promise that resolves to true. If it doesn't find the item, it resolves to false.

Here are the options as defined by MDN:

ignoreSearch: A Boolean that specifies whether to ignore the query string in the URL. For example, if set to true the ?value=bar part of

```
htt://foo.com/?value=bar
```

would be ignored when performing a match. It defaults to false.

ignoreMethod: A Boolean that, when set to true, prevents matching operations from validating the Request HTTP method (normally only GET and HEAD are allowed.) It defaults to false.

ignoreVary: A Boolean that when set to true tells the matching operation not to perform VARY header matching — that is, if the URL matches you will get a match regardless of whether the Response object has a VARY header. It defaults to false.

cacheName: A DOMString that represents a specific cache to search within. Note that this option is ignored by Cache.match().

Comment: I've updated my question to explain more. I've tried using cache.delete but it's returning false.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the testing localhost I was using (I think it's based of npm http-server) was messing with the cache and not letting me delete things. When testing using `py -m http.server` I have no issues.